# How can I transfer data between two files without segue?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

UIView is available as a separate file. How can I pass data between two files without a segue?

I am trying to pass data without using segue. I am using UIView in main viewcontroller. This UIView has a separate file. I want to transfer the data to that file and assign it to the variable.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class HesapView: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bakiyeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bakiyeTLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ibanOrKartLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ayrintiButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            print("hesap")
        case 1 :
            print("kart")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
     
    @IBAction func segmentControlTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            bakiyeLabel.text = "Kullanılabilir Bakiye"
            bakiyeTLabel.text = "\(AnasayfaVC().anaHesapBakiye) ₺"
            ibanOrKartLabel.text = "TR26 0000 0000 0000 0000 0050 01"
            ayrintiButton.setTitle("Tüm Hesaplar >", for: .normal)
        case 1 :
            bakiyeLabel.text = "Kullanılabilir Limit"
            bakiyeTLabel.text = "\(AnasayfaVC().anaKartLimit) ₺"
            ibanOrKartLabel.text = "Kart Numarası: 2600 0000 0000 0001"
            ayrintiButton.setTitle("Tüm Kartlar >", for: .normal)
        default:
            break
        }
        
    }
```

I want to show the retrieved data in UIView.

```
func getDataParseFromSegmentView() {
        
        let hesapQuery = PFQuery(className: "Hesaplar")
        hesapQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "3gBzkj3Bk1")
        
        hesapQuery.findObjectsInBackground { objects, error in
            if error != nil {
                self.alertYolla(titleInput: "Hata", messageInput: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Hata Oluştu.")
            } else {
                if objects != nil {
                    for object in objects! {
                        if let hesapAdi = object.objectId {
                            self.anaHesap = hesapAdi
                        }
                        if let hesapBakiye = object.object(forKey: "bakiye") as? String {
                            self.anaHesapBakiye = hesapBakiye
                        }
                        if let hesapIBAN = object.object(forKey: "hesapNo") as? String {
                            self.anaHesapIBAN = hesapIBAN
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        let kartQuery = PFQuery(className: "Kartlar")
        kartQuery.whereKey("kartNo", equalTo: "5026722530589834")
        kartQuery.findObjectsInBackground { objects, error in
            if error != nil {
                self.alertYolla(titleInput: "Hata", messageInput: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Hata Oluştu.")
            } else {
                if objects != nil {
                    for object in objects! {
                        if let kartNo = object.object(forKey: "kartNo") as? String {
                            self.anaKartNo = kartNo
                        }
                        if let kartLimit = object.object(forKey: "kalanLimit") as? String {
                            self.anaKartLimit = kartLimit
                        }
                        if let kartID = object.objectId {
                            self.anaKartID = kartID
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried assigning the file to the variable but without success.

```
let iuView = UIView()
iuView.variable1 = variable2

------------------------------
UIView

texField.text = variable1
```

I tried to do like the example above, it didn't work.

Comment: MainViewController has a `@IBOutlet` or a `var` `HesapView`, no? The view is inside that ViewController? If yes, just do `thatVar.value = someThing`

Comment: Use a public var or a public function in the destination view that can set this var. views are objects, so once created , they act as other objects.